# Relativistic energy from Lorentz contraction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics

Can one understand the relativistic energy formula in terms of the Lorentz contraction of the Compton wavelength?

If we take natural units with $\hbar=c=1$ then the energy of a particle at rest, $E_0$, is related to its proper Compton wavelength $L_0$ by

$$E_0=\frac{1}{L_0}.$$

If the particle is moving with velocity $v$ then its Compton wavelength is contracted

$$L=\frac{L_0}{\gamma}.$$

Its energy is then

$$E=\frac{1}{L}=\frac{\gamma}{L_0}=\gamma\ E_0,$$

which is the relativistic energy of a particle moving with velocity $v$.

Comment: Isn't $E_0 = \frac{1}{L_0}$ the definition of the compton wavelength? Why would you assume it length contracts?

Comment: The problem is that $E$ is not $1/L$ in the relativistic formulation unless the invariant mass is $0$, whereas the transformation property of  $E$ follows from the Loentz transformation of 4-vectors, which does not depend on the invariant mass.   The argument as suggested therefore cannot hold in general.

Comment: Perhaps I am implicitly modelling a massive particle as a zero mass particle confined as a standing wave in a  reflective box of length $L$?